# problem 11B of a course in combinatorics: Show by example that $M(k)\geq (k!)^{\frac{1}{k}}$.

Tags: combinatorics

Problem $11B$ in A Course in Combinatorics by van Lint and Wilson is the following:

> Prove that $M(n,k)\geq k!$. Prove that $M(k)\leq (k!)^{{\frac{1}{k}}}$. Show by example that $M(k)\geq (k!)^{{\frac{1}{k}}}$. This shows that $M(k)=(k!)^{{\frac{1}{k}}}$.

I have proved the first two parts, the first part by giving an example for a $ n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that each row and column have exactly $k$ ones, and $ per(A)=k!$. Since $M(n,k)$ is the maximum of permanents of such matrices, we are done.

for the second part, I need a proof check. Using
$$per A\leq \prod_{i=1}^{n}(r_i)!^{\frac{1}{r_i}}$$ we have $per(A)\leq (k!)^{\frac{n}{k}}$ thus $M(n,k)\leq (k!)^{\frac{n}{k}}$ $$ M(k)=\lim_{n \to \infty} M(n,k)^{1/n} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}(k!)^{\frac{1}{k}}=(k!)^{\frac{1}{k}}$$
giving us the desired result.

Now for the last part I'm stuck and I don't even fully understand, what does it mean to show by example that $M(k)\geq (k!)^{{\frac{1}{k}}}$? Hints or complete solution are appreciated!

Comment: You just need to prove the matching lower bound $M(n,k)\ge (k!)^{n/k}$, by finding, for each $n$ and $k$, an $n\times n$ binary matrix  $M_{n,k}$ with $k$ ones in each row and column for which $\text{per }M_{n,k}=(k!)^{n/k}. $ Then the limit will hold exactly.

Comment: Thanks, Now I understand what I should do. Now when $k|n$ I can easily find such matrix, to be specific a matrix which has $n/k$ blocks of $k\times k$ matrices which has 1 in every spot, on its main diagonal. I don't have an example for the general case.

Comment: Actually, that’s all you need! Since you just need to prove a limit, you only need to prove the $M(n,k)$ equality holds for infinitely many $n$. This is assuming it is known in advance that the limit will exist.